# Tortoise coordinate derivative

Tags: general-relativity, differentiation

According to [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington–Finkelstein_coordinates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington%E2%80%93Finkelstein_coordinates) the tortoise coordinate $r^*$ is defined as
$r + 2GM\ln(\frac{r}{2GM} -1)$

It then says that $\frac{dr^*}{dr}$ = $\frac{1}{1-\frac{2GM}{r}}$

However when I do the calculation myself, I find that $\frac{dr^*}{dr} = 1 + \frac{1}{\frac{r}{2GM}-1}$. I did this by using chain rule and taking $u$ = $\frac{r}{2GM} -1$ which is responsible for the $\frac{1}{u}$ term. Putting this into a derivative calculator gives me the same result.

So how do we get the expression that comes from Wikipedia?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/168783) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/168783) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Btw, your result is correct. Both expressions are equal, you just wrote them in two different ways. You just need a couple more steps of purely algebraic manipulation to get your result to the form displayed on wikipedia

Comment: But there’s a singularity at r=0 in Wikipedia’s result. (You get 1/(1-2GM/0)). But in my result there’s no singularity. So how can they be equal?

Comment: A singularity in the *denominator* means the whole expression is zero.

Comment: @Buzz yes I know. What I’m referring to is that we are subtracting by 2GM/0. How is something like that a sensible term?